# iOS how to identify which image (button) is pressed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, uiimage

I've three randomly generated images( actually UIButton) and when application runs it asks the user to choose one random image among the three(say a.png).after user select the image app will do some thing based on correct image was selected or not.

Now the question is that how can i identify that user select right image? I'm trying to get name of image that user select and then check it, but really no idea how to do that.
I've searched google for this but can't find something useful.

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: Look if pressed button checking can help u. Once u get clicked button, you can check which image was associated with that button

Comment: problem is that every time app runs or user select right image then it will generate next 3 random images, I've to access name of images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you really want to store the name of the image into the button, instead of using the `tag`property, you could set it to the title and hide the titleLabel ([apple reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) says: Although this property is read-only, its own properties are read/write. Use these properties to configure the appearance of the button label.):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

button.titleLabel.hidden = true;
[button setTitle:@"a.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

then you can access to the imagename with `button.currentTitle`.

Comment: Thanks Rene Jennrich. Hope this will help me.

Answer (score 3):

While generating your UIButtons you can fill the `tag` property.
Then you can check if your `sender.tag` equals the value you filled in.

When you only want to check if the correct image is selected, you can set only this one to `1` and the other buttons to `0`.

Comment: yes i can set tag property, but problem is that every time app runs or user select right image then it will generate next 3 random images, I've to access name of images?

Comment: do you know which image is correct when you assign it to the buttons?

Comment: yes app will ask to choose one image among the three and this way i've the name of correct image.

Comment: then when you know which image is correct while you generate the buttons, and can give to the correct button a tag with `1`, like i edited above.

Comment: I can't because(say i've 3 images a.png, b.png, c.png) and every time app will ask to choose different image, we can say correct image will be decided at run time. so can't fix the tag value for correct image.

Comment: ok, i've added another answer to store the image title. I do not know how you can access the name of the image in the UIImage, but you could use the title instead, look below.

Answer (score 2):

To know which button clicked u need to add tag say from 0, 1, 2

```
[yourButton setTag:0]; //set tag 1 and 2 also to other button
```

Now add same selector or method to all buttons:

```
[yourButton setTarget:@selector(buttonClicked:) forState:UIControlTouchUPInside];
// setTarget to other buttons too
```

method would be this:

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{

  if([sender tag] == 0)
  {
     //button 1 clicked
  }
  else if([sender tag] == 1)
  {
     //button 2 clicked
  }
  else if([sender tag] == 2)
  {
    //button 3 clicked
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are using `UIButton`s for this purpose, you could set `Target Selector`  on each button and determine the `UIButton` using their tag values.

Answer (score 0):

There's also one more method to help. But only of you use 'backgroundImage'.This action is should be linked with your buttons:

```
-(IBAction)photoIconClicked:(id)sender{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
        UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
        _currentImage = button.currentBackgroundImage;
    }
}
```